# what about the case $V_x=U_x$ in the proof of paracompactness Theorem (John Lee book)?

Tags: proof-explanation, differential-topology

Here the proof of "paracompactness Theorem" (Theorem 4.77) of the book "Introduction to topological manifold" - John M. Lee (2ed):

[image]

When $\mathcal{U} = \{W_j\}$ then $V_x = U_x \cap W_j = W_j = U_x$, and if the only subcover of $A_j$ from $W_j$ is $W_j$ itself, then the new constructed cover is just $U$, and we don't have refinement of $U$. Something wrong with my argument here?

**EDIT**: please, check this anwser. Since $W_j$ is open, for each point of $W_j$ there's an open ball in $W_j$ contains that point, then $W_j$ is not only subcover of $A_j$.

Comment: If $\mathcal{U} = \{W_j\}$ then $\mathcal{U}$ is already locally finite and that's okay. A refinement of a cover, by definitions, could be the cover itself (in that case is a trivial refinement).

Comment: @NoSignals, You're right. Could you put your comment in the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathcal{U}=\{Wj\}$ then $\mathcal{U}$ is already locally finite and that's okay. A refinement of a cover, by definitions, could be the cover itself (in that case is a trivial refinement).